# Is it possible to use "pass" in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to using pass in an if-else statement using list comprehension. Here's an example of what I am trying to do.

```py
result = [x if condition1 else y if condition2 else pass for x in lisst]
```

- The `condition1` and `condition2` are expressions that can depend on `x`
- If `condition1` is True, I want `x` to be inluded in the result.
- If `condition2` is True, I want `y` (some constant) to be included in the result.
- The `lisst` is a list of items

#### Problem

When both `condition1` and `condition2` are `False`, I want to `pass` (skip that `x`). How can I do it inside a list comprehension?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to filter out elements, then just use the dedicated syntax for it:

```py
[x for x in lisst if x == 2]
```

For your new edit:

```py
[x if x == 2 else 7 for x in lisst if x in (2, 5)]
```

For your third edit (please stop editing questions after people answer them):

```py
def func(x):
    if condition1:
        return x
    if condition2:
        return y
    return None

result = [v for v in [func(x) for x in lisst] if v is not None]
```

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my code snippet please review it again plz

Comment: I'm so sorry its not for a specific question I'm just asking how to implement a pass using list comprehension. Please review my additional edit

Answer (score 2):

Remember the Zen of Python: *Readability counts*. It is much better to write the code below as

```py
res = []
for x in L:
    if x == 2:
        res.append("B")
    elif x == 5:
        res.append("E")
    elif x == 7:
        res.append("G")
```

or, alternatively

```py
In [82]: d = {2:"B", 5:"E", 7:"G"}

In [83]: [d[x] for x in L if x in d]
Out[83]: ['E', 'G', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'G']
```

---

### List comprehensions 101

The syntax of list comprehension is<sup>1</sup>

```
[(expression) (for clause) (zero or more if clauses)]
```

- Inside the `(expression)`, if you have **`N`** different outputs,  you must have **`N-1`** *conditional expressions*.
- The **`pass`** is implemented implicitly by having **one or more if clauses** at the **right side** of the for clause.

In other words, the *mental model* for list comprehension is

```
[<output_options> (for clause) <filtering>]
```

For example:

```py
[x if x == 2 else 7 for x in L if (x in {2,5})]
```

---

### More comprehensive answer

Hard to grasp? Well, let me try to explain this one small piece at time. Let us have some example data:

```py
In [64]: L = [5, 7, 3, 1, 2, 5, 7, 3, 7]
```

### First steps

The simplest list comprehension would be to include all of the items:

```py
In [65]: [x for x in L]
Out[65]: [5, 7, 3, 1, 2, 5, 7, 3, 7]
```

well that's noop and boring, so let's try to filter it a bit

```py
In [66]: [x for x in L if x > 4]
Out[66]: [5, 7, 5, 7, 7]
```

### What is the correct syntax?

Let's now have a look on what the correct syntax is. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) says:

> A list comprehension consists of brackets containing **an expression**
> followed by a **for clause**, then **zero or more** for **or if clauses**

The additional for clauses are not of interest in this case. So what we are left to play with is

```
[(expression) (for clause) (zero or more if clauses)]
```

This is the syntax we must obey. Therefore, for example this would work:

```py
In [68]: [x for x in L if (x > 4) if (x < 6)]
Out[68]: [5, 5]
```

We can see that the **`expression`** on the **left** is used to select ***what*** to include and the **`if clauses`** on the **right** are used to ***filter out*** something.

### Continuing with our example

Let's say that we want

- output "B" if input is 2,
- output "E" if input is 5,
- output "G" if input is 7,
- output nothing (pass) otherwise.

#### Solving for the `(expression)` part

The selection logic must be **an expression**<sup>2</sup> and [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.3/whatsnew/pep-308.html) is a subtype of an expression with syntax

```
true_value if condition else false_value
```

Because we have ***three different outputs*** (for inputs 2, 5 and 7), the expression must therefore consist of ***two conditional expressions*** (because of the last `else`)<sup>3</sup>:

```
true_value1 if condition1 else (true_value2 if condition2 else false_value)
```

and after inserting the our conditions and desired outputs we have

```
"B" if (x == 2) else ("E" if (x==5) else "G")
```

Now the output looks like this

```py
In [69]: ["B" if (x == 2) else ("E" if (x==5) else "G") for x in L]
Out[69]: ['E', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'G', 'G']
```

### Filtering ("implicit pass")

As said earlier, the optional **if clauses** (zero or more) on the **right side** of the for clause can be used for filtering. Our filtering condition is that the `x` must be in `{2,5,7}`. Therefore, the **final list comprehension** is

```py
In [70]: ["B" if (x == 2) else ("E" if (x==5) else "G") for x in L if x in {2,5,7}]
Out[70]: ['E', 'G', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'G']
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The additional for clauses are not needed here. Full syntax is

```
[(expression) (for clause) (zero or more for/if clauses)]
```

<sup>2</sup> Something that evaluates down to a single value; something that you could use in `x = <expression>`.
<sup>3</sup> For `N` conditions (outputs) you need `N-1` conditional expressions (because of the last `else`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```py
def new(x):
   if condition1:
      return x
   if condition2:
      return y

result = [new(x) for x in lisst if new(x) is not None]
```

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my code snippet please review it again plz

Comment: I got what you mean, and I updated my solution, you can try it!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
L = [5,7,3,4,5,7,7]
result = [x if x == 2 else 7 for x in L if x in [2, 5]]
```

Result:

```
[7, 7]
```